# Polly final action after max retry

Tags: c#, exception, polly, retry-logic

The C# project that I'm working on uses Polly (v8.3) for resiliency. The code looks very much similar to the sample found [in the Github documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/docs/pipelines/index.md) :

```
ResiliencePipeline pipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
    .AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions{/*omitted*/})
    .Build();
```

and subsequently

```
pipeline.Execute(() => SomeVoidMethodThatMayFail());
```

The retry options have been omitted here, it boils down to that Polly will retry 5 times and on every failed attempt an entry is written to a log. As can be deduced from the use of a **non**-generic `RetryStrategyOptions`, the code that may throw an exception has a return type of `void`.

The last thing that I need to implement, is a 'finally'-block, e.g. send an email if the retries have been exhausted. I thought of using a [fallback](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/docs/strategies/fallback.md), but there is no non-generic `FallbackStrategyOptions`. What would be the appropriate Polly-way to execute code
after the last retry has failed? Of course, I could change my method to return e.g. `bool` instead of `void`, but that seems like a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strategy has exhausted all the retry attempts then it will throw the last exception. So, you need a `catch` block, not a `finally`

```
try
{
   pipeline.Execute(() => SomeVoidMethodThatMayFail());
   // The pipeline has succeeded without exhausting all retry attempts
}
catch(Exception ex) // The same exception type(s) as you have in your ShouldHandle
{
   // The pipeline has failed by exhausting all retry attempts
}
```

---

There is an API called [`ExecuteOutcomeAsync`](https://www.pollydocs.org/migration-v8.html#migrating-safe-execution) which is considered the successor of the `ExecuteAndCapture{Async}` safe methods. At the time of writing, it has only async API and your to-be-decorated method should return a `ValueTask<Outcome<TResult>>` which is not suitable for your use case.